# read only positive number else repeat

Tags: python, condiciones, bucles, else

como puedo cambiar el statement "else" para que se queda solocitar el valor hasta q sea positivo

mi codigo :

list = []

while (True):

```
size = int(input("cantidad de las valores a introducir " ))
for i in range(size):
    numbers = float(input(f" ingtresa el numero # {i+1}: "))
    if numbers >= 0 :

        list.append(numbers)
    else:
        print ("numero incorrecto intenta otra vez")
        continue
med = sum(list)/len(list)
print(list)
print (med)
```

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna pregunta o sólo quieres el código?

Comment: Two things: First this site is Stack Overflow for Spanish speakers, so the communication need to be in Spanish. Second I suggest you to use a **while** instead of For and only increment the i inside the if.

Comment: la aplicacion tiene q soicitar los numeros en el raange del talla si hay un numero negativo tiene q solicitar otra vez hasta q sea positivo. entiendo tu idea pero como reformarla gracias .

Answer (score 0):

Basándome en tu código te recomiendo lo siguiente dependiendo de lo que exactamente quieres, teniendo en cuenta que en todos los casos el valor que pide ingresar debe ser positivo:

- Se queda notificando que el valor es erróneo y pide nuevamente ingresar el valor:

```
    list = []
    size = int(input("cantidad de las valores a introducir " ))
    for i in range(size):
        while True:
          numbers = float(input(f" ingtresa el numero # {i+1}: "))
          if numbers >= 0 :
              list.append(numbers)
              break
          else:
              print ("numero incorrecto intenta otra vez")
    med = sum(list)/len(list)
    print(list)
    print (med)
```

- Solo pide nuevamente ingresar el valor:

```
    list = []
    size = int(input("cantidad de las valores a introducir " ))
    for i in range(size):
        while True:
          numbers = float(input(f" ingtresa el numero # {i+1}: "))
          if numbers >= 0 :
              list.append(numbers)
              break
    med = sum(list)/len(list)
    print(list)
    print (med)
```

- Ingreso el siguiente código por si lo llegas a necesitar en este ejercicio o en alguno parecido. Este código te permite pedir que el usuario ingrese un número estrictamente positivo y entero, no permite negativos ni flotantes:

```
    while True:
      valor = input("Ingrese un número entero positivo: ")
      if str.isdigit(valor):
        valor = int(valor)
        break
      else:
        print("El dato ingresado no es un número entero positivo. Intente de nuevo.")
```